# stop touchmove event for popup dialog

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, mobile

Creating app for mobile devices. So the Issue: I need to show popup dialog when user click the link on page. Page shoud be frozen during popup is showing (disable scroll). Inside popup I have long list with items that shoud be scrolled. So how I implemented it:

I creating popup inside body, and I'm adding next code to prevent scroll:

```
$("body").bind("touchmove", scrollHandler);

function scrollHandler(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Inside popup I added list which should be scrolled but ofcours it's not scrolled because it prevented by previous handler. So how to enable scroll for list inside popup. Thanks

Comment: how abt setting `overflow:hidden` to body before u open popup and remove that property when closing it? Its always worked for me! :)

Comment: and it could be `$("body").bind("touchmove",false);` instead of the function call! this will also work :) and are you using jquery mobile?

Comment: overflow:hidden doesn't work for mobilw browsers, they have own scrollbar. Nope I didn't use jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founs solvation:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, oldScrollPosition)
});
```

If you it will help to someone :) Need to manipulate scroll insted of touch events.